# How can i upgrade my npm version in windows 10?

Tags: npm

I want to upgrade to npm version in between 5-6, since I'm getting the start command error frequently.

When I typed the upgrade command for npm like this:

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
```

In the first phase, I get the following error:

> ```
> npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
> ```

Please can anyone help me out!

Comment: lastly resolved, by removing old version of npm and setting the path variables to the newly installed `nodejs folder`. Now perfectly showing my latest version of npm and node!!